# What armors come with the Falskaar mod?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods, skyrim-falskaar

### Images? Video? Either would be wonderful.

I need to know before I download the mod.I'ma stickler for aesthetics, and how my PC looks. I want to see them and make my decision rather than find out later, and decide that I don't like them or something, which would be a waste of my time to even look for them. Making part of the mod just a disappointment since I know it doesn't exactly uninstall easily... I'll probably still try it if I don't like them... I just won't go looking for any armors, I guess.

**I already know some of them of are recolors while others are new.**
But I sat for a while trying to find video or images taken of the armors, but I couldn't. 
Not directly it seemed anyway.

Comment: Don't play Falskaar because of the armors, play it because the quests are great.

Comment: Well yeah of course! I just wanna be disappointing if I go looking for stoof. ^ u ^;

Answer (score 2):

They're all just recolors or just renamed models and textures from the base game, the fixed ceremonial armor might be edited from the normal version a bit, but that's about it. All the armors that are usable by the player are below with images.

Click the image for fullsize version.

---

### Damaged Ceremonial Armor

[image: Damaged Ceremonial Armor]

---

### Fixed Ceremonial Armor

*Notice the yellow ring on the back*

[image: Fixed Ceremonial Armor]

---

### Fitted Guard Armor (whole set)

[image: Fitted Guard Armor set]

---

### Reinforced Guard Armor (whole set)

[image: Reinforced Guard Armor set]

---

### Staalgarde Armor (whole set with shield)

[image: Staalgarde Armor set]

---

### Fine Clothes of Glibness & Rubied Sapphire Necklace

[image: Fine Clothes of Glibness and Rubied Sapphire Necklace]